# What's on Rose's shoulder when she's contemplating suicide (Titanic)?

Tags: character, plot-explanation, props, titanic

What's this black semicircle thing on Rose's left shoulder (scene where she's prepping to jump off Titanic)?

It almost looks like a fake eyelash. It disappears after this shot, and afterward, is seen on neither shoulder again. It looks too oddly out of place to be part of the dress' design, in my opinion.

[image: Left shoulder]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just a piece of the material from her dress which has slipped down. A second or two before your first picture, it's visible as she walks towards the guardrail at the stern of the boat. I'm guessing once they did the closeups, they made sure the dress was properly fixed so it couldn't be seen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To heck with it, I'm going to convert my comment to an answer:

I'm pretty sure the marking is just **some of the fabric of her dress that has come down from her shoulder**. If you pause the scene just a few frames before your first image, you can see the same mark in that position.

I assume that when they filmed the more close up shots they deliberately fixed it (or the scene was spliced together from different takes, some with the fabric a little low like in your pictures, others not).